# Can't detect face in images that capture by camera of Iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, image

I have a problem. I use 2 image. One is download from internet. the other is captured by camera of iPhone.
I use **CIDetector** to  detect face in 2 images. It work perfect in image that download from internet. But the other, it's can't detect or detect wrong.

I check in many images. That result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: CIDetectorAccuracyLow            forKey: CIDetectorAccuracy];
        CIDetector  *detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType: CIDetectorTypeFace context:    nil options: options];

      CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage: [image CGImage]];
    NSNumber *orientation = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[image imageOrientation]+1];
    NSDictionary *fOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:orientation forKey: CIDetectorImageOrientation];
        NSArray *features = [detector featuresInImage:ciImage options:fOptions];
        for (CIFaceFeature *f in features) {

            NSLog(@"left eye found: %@", (f. hasLeftEyePosition ? @"YES" : @"NO"));

            NSLog(@"right eye found: %@", (f. hasRightEyePosition ? @"YES" : @"NO"));

            NSLog(@"mouth found: %@", (f. hasMouthPosition ? @"YES" : @"NO"));

            if(f.hasLeftEyePosition)

                NSLog(@"left eye position x = %f , y = %f", f.leftEyePosition.x, f.leftEyePosition.y);

            if(f.hasRightEyePosition)

                NSLog(@"right eye position x = %f , y = %f", f.rightEyePosition.x, f.rightEyePosition.y);

            if(f.hasMouthPosition)

                NSLog(@"mouth position x = %f , y = %f", f.mouthPosition.x, f.mouthPosition.y);

        }
```

if you're using the front camera always in portrait  add this

```
      NSDictionary* imageOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber        numberWithInt:6] forKey:CIDetectorImageOrientation];
      NSArray* features = [detector featuresInImage:image options:imageOptions];
```

For more info

sample: https://github.com/beetlebugorg/PictureMe

[iOS Face Detection Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121427/ios-face-detection-issue)

[Face Detection issue using CIDetector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154585/face-detection-issue-using-cidetector)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332868/detect-face-in-iphone?rq=1

Comment: The big problem is it's can't detect when I use image that just captured by camera of Iphone

Comment: But if i set **NSDictionary* imageOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber        numberWithInt:6] forKey:CIDetectorImageOrientation];** Image that downloaded in internet can't be detect if it is landscape.........:(

Comment: Have you tried the above? Is it working now for captured image from iPhone?update your question with your code used for face detection.

Comment: Can we know the image captured by Iphone is captured by front camera or back camera ?

Answer (score 0):

I try to this code above. It's can detect images captured by Iphone. But it's can't detect image download from Internet. This is my code

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: CIDetectorAccuracyLow            forKey: CIDetectorAccuracy];
CIDetector  *detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType: CIDetectorTypeFace context:    nil options: options];

CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage: [facePicture CGImage]];
NSDictionary* imageOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber        numberWithInt:6] forKey:CIDetectorImageOrientation];
NSArray *features = [detector featuresInImage:ciImage options:imageOptions];
```

And when it's detect face. I show by code

```
for (CIFaceFeature *feature in features) {
```

//        // Set red feature color

```
    CGRect faceRect = [feature bounds];

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0f * scale);
    CGContextAddRect(context, feature.bounds);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, faceRect, [imgDraw CGImage]);
```

it's not right position. It's move to right a distance.

Comment: Please add this to your question.Better remove it from answer

Comment: please Wait. more experienced guys will help you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You can change size of the image before detection.

```
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(cameraCaptureImage.size.width, cameraCaptureImage.size.height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
[cameraCaptureImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
cameraCaptureImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```